# How do I retain only strings after a pattern in a column

Tags: awk, sed

I will appreciate any help with my file. I have a file with 4 columns

```
Accession   Description     logFC  p-value

P7852  DNA-dependent protein kinase catalytic subunit OS=Homo sapiens GN=PRKDC PE=1 SV=3       -0.183343951    0.006947985

Q13085  Acetyl-CoA carboxylase 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ACACA PE=1 SV=2     -1.250658294    0.012223886

A0A1W7HHM5      Major DNA-binding protein OS=Epstein-Barr virus (strain GD1) GN=DBP PE=3 SV=1   0.176282017     2.69897E-05

A0A0S2YRG9      Major DNA-binding protein OS=Epstein-Barr virus (strain GD1) GN=BALF2 PE=3 SV=1 2.707961346     0.015657277
```

I want to retain only the gene name after the pattern "GN=" in column 2 to have an output like this

```
Accession   Description logFC   p-value

P78527  PRKDC   -0.183343951    0.006947985

Q13085  ACACA   -1.250658294    0.012223886

A0A1W7HHM5  DBP 0.176282017     2.69897E-05

A0A0S2YRG9  BALF2   2.707961346     0.015657277
```

I tried this code but it excluded column1 and still retained part of column2

`awk -F"GN=" '/GN=/{print $2}' file`

Comment: what is the input column delimiter? tab? multiple spaces? something else? the 2nd column (`Description`) appears to contain spaces so we need to know how to distinguish between white space as column delimiter vs white space as column data

Comment: The file is tab-delimited but description in column 2 contains whitespaces.

Comment: does the input file contain blank lines (as currently depicted)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v ptn="GN" '                          # define our search pattern
BEGIN  { FS=OFS="\t" }                     # input/output field delimiter is a tab
FNR==1 { print; next }                     # print header record; skip to next line of input
       { n=split($2,a,/[[:space:]]/)       # split 2nd field on white space; store results in array a[]
         for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {              # loop through a[] array
             m=split(a[i],b,/=/)           # split each item on "="; store results in array b[]
             if (b[1]==ptn) {              # if we found "<ptn>=" then ...
                $2=b[2]                    # reset entire 2nd field to b[2] and ...
                break                      # break out of loop
             }
         }
         print                             # print current line to stdout
       }
' file
```

This generates:

```
Accession       Description     logFC   p-value

P7852   PRKDC   -0.183343951    0.006947985

Q13085  ACACA   -1.250658294    0.012223886

A0A1W7HHM5      DBP     0.176282017     2.69897E-05

A0A0S2YRG9      BALF2   2.707961346     0.015657277
```

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` uses `match` to find the desired field and removes the string with `sub`.

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print} 
       NR>1 && NF > 0{
       for(i = 2; i <= NF; i++){
         m = match($i, "GN=")
         if(m != 0){field = i
           sub("GN=", "", $field)
         }
       }
       print $1, $field, $(NF-1), $NF }' file
Accession Description logFC p-value
P78527 PRKDC -0.183343951 0.006947985
Q13085 ACACA -1.250658294 0.012223886
A0A1W7HHM5 DBP 0.176282017 2.69897E-05
A0A0S2YRG9 BALF2 2.707961346 0.015657277
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk`-based solution without calling either `match()` or `split()`, or using either arrays or loops

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN { FS = (OFS = "\11" )( (_="") ".* GN=" )
>
>       } NR==!_ || sub("( [^=]+=[!-~]+)+",_, $!(NF = NF))'
> ```

```
Accession    Description    logFC    p-value
P7852    PRKDC    -0.183343951    0.006947985
Q13085    ACACA    -1.250658294    0.012223886
A0A1W7HHM5    DBP    0.176282017    2.69897E-05
A0A0S2YRG9    BALF2    2.707961346    0.015657277
```

another approach :

> ```
> nawk 'BEGIN { FS = "[" (_=" ")(__ = OFS = "\t")"].* GN="
>               RS = "(\r?\n)+"; ___ ^= _ = (_ "[^")__ "]+" 
>             } NR ==___ || sub(_,__,$(NF = NF) )'
> ```

if you prefer a more orderly look without using `column` or manually adjusting column widths :

> ```
> gawk 'BEGIN { FS = (OFS = "\t" )( (_="") ".* GN=" )
>                   __ = "\v\r\t"
> } (NR==!_?_:sub("( [^=]+=[!-~]+)+",_,$!(NF=NF)))+gsub("[ \t]+",__)'
> ```

```
Accession
    Description
    logFC
    p-value
P7852
    PRKDC
    -0.183343951
    0.006947985
Q13085
    ACACA
    -1.250658294
    0.012223886
A0A1W7HHM5
    DBP
    0.176282017
    2.69897E-05
A0A0S2YRG9
    BALF2
    2.707961346
    0.015657277
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
Accession   Description     logFC  p-value

P7852  DNA-dependent protein kinase catalytic subunit OS=Homo sapiens GN=PRKDC PE=1 SV=3       -0.183343951    0.006947985

Q13085  Acetyl-CoA carboxylase 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ACACA PE=1 SV=2     -1.250658294    0.012223886

A0A1W7HHM5      Major DNA-binding protein OS=Epstein-Barr virus (strain GD1) GN=DBP PE=3 SV=1   0.176282017     2.69897E-05

A0A0S2YRG9      Major DNA-binding protein OS=Epstein-Barr virus (strain GD1) GN=BALF2 PE=3 SV=1 2.707961346     0.015657277
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[[:space:]].*GN="}{$1=$1;print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Accession   Description     logFC  p-value

P7852 PRKDC PE=1 SV=3       -0.183343951    0.006947985

Q13085 ACACA PE=1 SV=2     -1.250658294    0.012223886

A0A1W7HHM5 DBP PE=3 SV=1   0.176282017     2.69897E-05

A0A0S2YRG9 BALF2 PE=3 SV=1 2.707961346     0.015657277
```

Explanation: firstly I identified what exactly should be done - remove everything from first whitespace to `GN=` (inclusive), in order to do that I informed GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) is single whitespaces character, followed by zero or more (`*`) of any character (`.`) followed by `GN=`. Then for each line I do `$1=$1` to trigger rebuilt and `print` its' effect.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*